# Eclipse changes current file

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am using Eclipse Neon.1 and was wondering if anyone else has had experience with the editor changing the current active file in the editor? It looks like if there is an error in another file that eclipse will change to that file automatically which is quite annoying especially if you are trying to fix the error when the actual error is in another file.

Is there a setting in Eclipse that controls this type of behavior? I have looked through the Eclipse site for this behavior but can't find anything describing it. I have also gone through all the settings under Window->Preferences but still can't find a setting that might be causing this.

Comment: What kind of files are you editing? What exactly happens to trigger the switch?

Comment: @E-Riz I appologize I am editing C++ files (.h, .cpp). Like I mentioned in my question it seems to happen if there is an compiler error somewhere. For example I might say change a member type in a Class Header then before I can update to the source file it will keep changing to the Header almost like eclipse wants me to fix the error first.

Comment: Hi @AndyBraham Coming a little late to the party, but Neon.0 and Neon.1 had a bug that has been fixed in Neon.2 (just about to be released) Perhaps this is the issue you have been facing: https://bugs.eclipse.org/507148

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jonah mentioned, you're running into [Eclipse bug 507148](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=507148), which was fixed in Neon.2.